# Multithread test C application hangs unless a printf is used

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm attempting to learn the ins and out of multithreading in C. I've started with this little example:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h> //Header file for sleep(). man 3 sleep for details. 
#include <pthread.h> 

#define TOTAL_TS  1000
#define WAIT_TS   74

int timeStepCounter;

// A normal C function that is executed as a thread 
// when its name is specified in pthread_create() 
void *longProcess(void *vargp) 
{ 
   int endtime = timeStepCounter + WAIT_TS;
    while (timeStepCounter < endtime);
    printf("Finished when timeStepCounter is %d\n",timeStepCounter); 
    return NULL; 
} 

int main() 
{ 

   pthread_t thread_id; 

   for (timeStepCounter = 0; timeStepCounter < TOTAL_TS; timeStepCounter++){
      if (timeStepCounter == 158){         
         printf("Creating thread @ %d\n",timeStepCounter);
         pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, longProcess, NULL); 
      }    
      //printf("TimeStep is: %d\n",timeStepCounter);
   }

   pthread_join(thread_id, NULL); 
   printf("Finished\n"); 

   return 0;

}
```

I've modified it from an internet example.

So here is what happens. When you run it as is, the program hangs after printing the "Creating thread ..." Message.

If, however, I uncomment the printf that prints the TimeStep, the application works as expected.

So my question is why?

EDIT: As suggested by @Bodo I'm putting a link to the internet example that was my basis for my code: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-c-2/

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to use global variables like `timeStepCounter`. It's even worse to use them between several threads, and they are not `volatile`, and you have absolutely no control when they are being changed. An optimizing compiler could replace your `while` loop with `while (true);` without much grief. Anyway: what happens with `timeStepCounter` if your `for` loop finishes before the thread is even started?

Comment: This is exactly what happens when the main thread does not get delayed by calling `printf`. Add a line `printf("Thread started when timeStepCounter is %d\n",timeStepCounter);` before `while (timeStepCounter < endtime);` and you will probably see `Thread started when timeStepCounter is 1000`.

Comment: What you mention, I believe is only a problem when you modify a global varaible from several threads. However my intention is to modify it in only in one thread. I will see how to program around what you've mentioned though! Thanks!

Comment: I've added the line @Bodo mentioned and it was just as he said. Whenever you guys want give an answer and I'll mark it a correct. Thank you!

Comment: @aarelovich It might be good to add a link to the "internet example" to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [groo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69809/groo)'s comment, the program does not work correct if the newly created thread starts execution when the main thread has already finished the loop.

This probably happens when the main thread does not get delayed by calling `printf`.

Add a line

```
printf("Thread started when timeStepCounter is %d\n",timeStepCounter);
```

before

```
while (timeStepCounter < endtime);
```

and you will probably see

```
Thread started when timeStepCounter is 1000
```

Additionally you must declare variables that are accessed by more than one thread as `volatile`, i.e.

```
volatile int timeStepCounter;
```

and make sure that it uses a type with atomic access. (If it was not atomic, you would need synchronization.)

Even if only one thread modifies the value, a compiler with optimization will find that `timeStepCounter` is not modified in the loop

```
while (timeStepCounter < endtime);
```

and produce code like

```
while(1);
```

The keyword `volatile` informs the compiler that the value may get modified outside the normal flow of the program what happens when you use threads. (The compiler does not know about threads.)

I can verify this by compiling the code without `volatile` and with the uncommented `printf` with

```
gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O3    test.c  -lpthread -o test
```

I get e.g.

```
...
Creating thread @ 158
...
Thread started when timeStepCounter is 226
...
```

but no

```
Finished when timeStepCounter is ...
```